# pointed data in function with malloc keeps disappearing outside of it

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I created two struct

```
typedef struct node
{
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
    int data;
} node;

typedef struct head
{
    int count;
    struct node* root;
} head;
```

and here's the function that i'm trying to use to insert data into a tree.

```
int insert(struct node* root, int value)
{
    node* newnode =(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->data=value;
    newnode->left=NULL;
    newnode->right=NULL;
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        root=newnode;
        return 1;
    }
    if(value<root->data)
    {
        if(root->left==NULL)
        {
            root->left=newnode;
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return insert(root->left,value);
        }
    }
    else if(value==root->data)
    {
        printf("data already exist\n");
        free(newnode);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if(root->right==NULL)
        {
            root->right=newnode;
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return insert(root->right,value);
        }
    }
}
```

and when i operate

```
head* BSThead=(head*)malloc(sizeof(head));
insert(BSThead->root,10);
```

i can see that insert function successfully enters the first if and operate the line root=newnode;, and i can see the address that it had given.

but when this function ends and i go back to the main function to access it through
    printf("%d",BSThead->root);

this line just prints 0, which I think means BST->root is currently null.

By what I have learned, the data created by malloc function has the scope over it's function unlike normal value. So I thought although newnode was created in the insert function, doesn't get destroyed like normal variables when the insert function ends and thus i can use it all the time while program runs.

Comment: You probably need to pass a pointer to the root node pointer to the function.  Or you can return the new root node pointer from the function.  There are many problems on SO that have this same basic diagnosis.  However, you're also passing unchecked, uninitialized data from `malloc()` to the function and that can lead to lots of trouble too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines:

```
if(root==NULL)
{
    root=newnode;
    return 1;
}
```

modify `root` in the function but don't change the value of the same variable in the calling function.

The value of `root` in the calling function continues to be NULL and you leak every node allocated by the call to `malloc`.

One way to fix this is to pass a pointer to `root`.

```
int insert(struct node** root, int value)
{
    ...
    if(*root==NULL)
    {
       *root=newnode;
       return 1;
    }

   ...
}
```

and call the function using:

```
insert(&(BSThead->root),10);
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you are using:

```
head* BSThead = (head*)malloc(sizeof(head));
insert(BSThead->root, 10);
```

This passes an unchecked pointer to uninitialized data to the function.  Only if you're unlucky will that be a null pointer that you're passing.  The function cannot modify the value in `BSThead->root` because you are passing its value, not a pointer to it.  You also aren't passing the whole of the `head` structure, so the `insert()` code cannot update the count.

You need to initialize your head structure before using it.  When you do use it, you need to pass either a pointer to the head structure into the function, or you need to pass the address of the `root` member to the function so that the function can update it:

```
head* BSThead = (head*)malloc(sizeof(head));
if (BSThead != 0)
{
    BSThead->count = 0;
    BSThead->root = 0;
    /* Either */
    insert(BSThead, 10);         // And insert can update the count
    /* Or */
    insert(&BSThead->root, 10);  // But insert can't update the count!
    …use the list…
    …free the list…
}
```